# Adding custom picture with parse push notification (swiftlang)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

In an Ios dating kind of app, is it possible to add a custom (profile)picture in a Parse push notification. So another user can decide directly from the push notification whether he is going to accept/decline the notification and open the app or not.

Obviously, default settings is the app icon of the app in the push notification.

Hope you can help me with this.

Cheers!

Tjalling